# How to use XmlUrlResolver to fix "XML External Entity (XXE)" attack?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, veracode

We have run `Veracode` and some `.cs` files turned out to be with security flow of `Improper Restriction of XML External Entity Reference ('XXE')`

A few month ago, when having the same sort of problem with different application, I solved the problem with addition of:

`settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Prohibit;`

Now, applying the same fix, does not solve the problem.

I have tried every possible solution offered to resolve the XXE issue, but it did not help.

I also had:

```
XmlDocument doc = null;

.....

settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Prohibit;
settings.XmlResolver = null;

....

doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.XmlResolver = null;
```

But it does not solve it as well.

So, I run across other offered solution of creating custom resolver class.

Now, I have the following code:

```
XmlDocument doc = null;
using (System.IO.MemoryStream xmlstream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(dsEQ.GetXml().ToString())))
{
   XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings { XmlResolver = new CustomeResolver() };
   settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Prohibit;
   settings.XmlResolver = null;
   using (XmlReader xmlreader = XmlReader.Create(xmlstream, settings))
   {
       try
       {
           doc = new XmlDocument();
           doc.XmlResolver = null;
           doc.Load(xmlreader);
       }
       catch (XmlException e)
       {
          Connection.LogError(e.ToString(), e.Message);
       }
    }
 }
```

And this is a custom resolver class:

```
private class CustomeResolver : XmlUrlResolver
{
    public override object GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, string role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
    {
         return base.GetEntity(absoluteUri, role, ofObjectToReturn);
    }
}
```

Before deploying the changes, I'm wondering if I used that class the right way and if not, how to change it and will it fix the problem at all?